# How can I post an HTML/Google Sheets table by preserving its format into the MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, backend

I am currently working on a project with React, which is kind of a blog site. Here I have to take tables from Google Sheet and send it to the database via Html text-area or form. I have tried to send the data through the text area, but the data is not preserved as a table in DB. In this case, how can I post the tables in the database and get the data in the same format?

Comment: Can you provide your current code? I will correct it.

Comment: @MikeSteelson Here it is - https://github.com/fahimrayhan/BLOG_SITE_FULL_STACK